# Delphi Progress Bar

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a progress bar that starts at 0%, and takes 5 seconds to get to 100%. The progress bar will begin to go up as soon as Button1 is clicked. Any advice? I looked on Google, but that gave me nothing good on this sort of thing.

Also, at 0%, there should be a label that says `Waiting...`, when the progress bar starts, it should go to `Working...`, and when it's done, it should say `Done!`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GetTickCount() and initializing variables:

```
uses Windows;

var mseconds, starttime: integer;


procedore TForm1.FormCreate()
begin
  starttime := GetTickCount();
  mseconds := 0;
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Label1.Caption := '';
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  Label1.Caption := 'Waiting...';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
  ProgressBar.Max := 100;
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  timer1.Enabled := True;
  Label1.Caption := 'Working...';  
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  mseconds := GetTickCount() - starttime;
  if mseconds < 5000 then
    ProgressBar1.Position := Trunc(mseconds / 50)
  else begin
    ProgressBar1.Position := 100;
    Label1.Caption := 'Done!';
    Timer1.Enabled := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ok. Your's had a few errors, but I am able to fix them up. For some reason though, when I hit the button, the label changes to Working..., but it does nothing else after that. I looked though to see if anything was wrong, could it be caused by: starttime := GetTickCount(); (read next comment)

Comment: and mseconds := starttime - GetTickCount();?

Comment: @PuppyKevin: You are on the right track; if you don't see the error then use the debugger, and you will find it. Also, Timer1 is not disabled when done...

Answer (score 9):

You can use a timer with interval 50 and firstly set enabled to false.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  cnt: integer = 1;
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := cnt;
  if cnt = 1 then Label1.Caption := 'Waiting...'
  else if cnt = 100 then begin
    Label1.Caption := 'Done!';
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
  end else
    Label1.Caption := 'Working...';
  Inc(cnt);
end;
```

Comment: One problem with using timers is that there is no guarantee it will take 5 seconds (2.5 in your example btw). Most of the times it will be a very close match. In a stressfull environment, it could be of by a magnitude of seconds.

Comment: @Lieven: You are right, but the influence of this can be minimized by a less dumb algorithm: don't count the timer ticks, but calculate the elapsed time since the start in the event handler. For higher message priority post a WM_USER each 100 ms from a background thread instead.

Comment: Yep.  This isn't a perfect solution, but the basic idea is correct

Comment: Ok, I tried your code, and I run into a few problems. On my form, I have a TButton, TProgressBar, TTimer, and a TLabel. I copy and pasted the code, but it says that "Timer does not contain a member 'Enabled'". Same goes with Tprogressbar.Position, and Label1.Caption. What could I be missing?

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: My Turbo Delphi application tells me that it uses Version 10 Delphi.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've the error. But in the error message you've Timer. What is Timer?
Do you have  
    Timer1: TTimer;   
in your Form class. And also check your label, progressbar and form names.

Comment: Under form class, I have ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;, Button1: TButton;,Timer1: TTimer;,Label1: TLabel;. The TProgressBar, TButton, TTimer, and TLabel also have a error, saying "Undeclared Identifier '<insert one of the four>'".

Comment: You will also need to add a {$J+} directive to allow the const cnt: integer = 1; to be modified. Better to use a field of the object (FCnt : integer) for this. Also need to set FCnt back to 1 before or after each run.